# Imageview not showing all image

Tags: android

Hello i am showing images in android app using gallery. I am having problem in displaying images. Some images are displayed some are not.

My adapter code is as follows:

```
ImageView iv;
            LinearLayout layoutnew = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
            layoutnew.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            if (convertView == null)
            {
                iv = new ImageView(ctx);
                iv.setBackgroundDrawable(m_docs_ids[arg0]);
                iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                int temp =(int) (height/1.7f);
                int temp_y = (int) ((3*temp)/2.0f);
                iv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ));

            }


 else
            {
                iv = (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            TextView tv = new TextView(ctx);

       //     tv.setText(m_docs.get(arg0).DocPath);
            tv.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
            tv.setPadding(0, 15, 0, 0);
            tv.setTag(arg0);
            tv.setTextSize(18);
            tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ));
            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            layoutnew.addView(iv);
            layoutnew.addView(tv);

            return layoutnew;
```

m_docs_id is a list of drawable type. i have debug it and found that it is getting correct entry. gallery is showing black for images which are not shown.

I found put that pictures placed in DCIM folders are not shown. all other images are shown

Comment: could you put your xml please

Comment: `Some images are displayed some are not.` Are all the images of supported types?

Comment: i found out that pictures in DCIM folders are not shown all other images are shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got my problem solved. Issue was not in DCIM folder, issue was in size. The pictures taken from cell phone camera is very high and gallery was not getting those images. I set size in drawables of photo with mobile screen size. Now its running f9

Answer (score 0):

you initialize the `imageView`like this `iv = new ImageView(ctx);`

you should initilize the `imageView` like this `iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mImageView);`

Comment: thanks for replying. but i am generating imageview at runtime

Comment: sir one more thing i found out that pictures in dcim folders are not shown.

Comment: dcim folders, set a path for accessing it